# iOS Parse SDK: How to check if login is from Facebook or Twitter?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, authentication, parse-platform

I have an app that allows users to log in to either Facebook or Twitter. There is a single

```
-(void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController )logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser )user
```

method that manages login from the PFLogInViewController. How do I check if user pressed the Facebook login button or the Twitter login button? I have functionality in my app that requires a different setup depending on the log in type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in `logInViewController:didLogInUser:` … check this

```
BOOL linkedWithFacebook = [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user];
BOOL linkedWithTwitter = [PFTwitterUtils isLinkedWithUser:user];
```

If it’s none of the above… it’s logged with "normal” PARSE username / password…

Happy codding!

Comment: you saved me again! That was exactly what I was looking for. Every time I read an answer from you I know it is short, to the point, and accurate. Thanks so much my friend.

Comment: You may also have anonymous login, this can be checked also: BOOL userIsAnonymous = [PFAnonymousUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];